# Displaying records using inner join sql query from more than 2 combinations parameters in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, search, inner-join

I am new to PHP and SQL; I am writing a SQL query to display records with the following logic:

1. There are 9 cells in sql table. I want to search records using combinations of 3 parameters. That are search between 2 dates, search in location and search in property category type.
2. Search criteria looks like this:

> Date From : _________(date picker) - Date Till:______________(date picker)
>
> Sales Agent : Dropdown ( dehi, mumbai,.....,)
>
> Mobile : __________ (text)

Results Combination Required:

a. All 3 combination True - (User Fills the date, sales agent, mobile.)

b. Either of the combination is True. (User only fills either of one parameter.)

c. Only 2 Combination are True. (User fills 2 parameter combination ie, date and mobile(or) mobile & sales agent (or) sales agent & date)

**Problem**: I'm not able to do only one combination.

Here is my SQL query and page syntax:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $date11=$_POST["date1"];
    $date22=$_POST["date2"];
    $salesagent1=$_POST["salesagent"];
    $mobile1=$_POST["mobile"];

    $result = "select 
                 ordertable.order_date, 
                 ordertable.order_id,
                 customer.cust_name, 
                 customer.cust_mobile,
                 customer.cust_email,
                 customer.cust_city,
                 ordertable.quantity, 
                 ordertable.total,
                 orderstatus.order_sta,
                 salesagent.name
               from customer inner join ordertable 
                 on customer.custid=ordertable.cust_id inner join salesagent 
                 on salesagent.said=ordertable.sales_id inner join orderstatus 
                 on orderstatus.id= (select order_statusid from orderhistory where order_id1= ordertable.order_id  order by date_added desc limit 1)                 
               where (ordertable.order_date between '$date11' and '$date22') or (customer.cust_mobile='$mobile1') or (ordertable.sales_id='$salesagent1') 
               order by ordertable.order_id desc";

    $records=mysqli_query($CON,$result);
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `null` or whatever you choose to do, to each parameters when it is empty:

```
$result = "select 
         ordertable.order_date, 
         ordertable.order_id,
         customer.cust_name, 
         customer.cust_mobile,
         customer.cust_email,
         customer.cust_city,
         ordertable.quantity, 
         ordertable.total,
         orderstatus.order_sta,
         salesagent.name
         from customer inner join ordertable 
         on customer.custid=ordertable.cust_id inner join salesagent 
         on salesagent.said=ordertable.sales_id inner join orderstatus 
         on orderstatus.id= (select order_statusid from orderhistory where order_id1= ordertable.order_id  order by date_added desc limit 1) 

        where ('$date11' IS NULL OR '$date22' IS NULL OR ordertable.order_date between '$date11' and '$date22') AND ('$mobile1' IS NULL OR customer.cust_mobile='$mobile1') AND ('$salesagent1' IS NULL OR ordertable.sales_id='$salesagent1') 
         order by ordertable.order_id desc";
```